# How do I restrict an android app to be available on only devices that accept a sim card?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm working on an app that uses a feature that is only available if the device can receive a text message. How can I ensure that the app is only compatible with sim-card acceptable devices?

Comment: This should do the job (add it to AndroidManifest): <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>

Comment: @bluefalcon no, is not a duplicate of that, the user wants to know if the SIM is available before runnnig the app

Comment: @MatPag you are right, retracting my vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use uses-feature flag in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

By using this it will filter simless devices for you.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use a flag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Add the uses-feature line to your manifest in this way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="your.package.app">

    <!-- Add this line to your manifest -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />

    <!-- other declarations -->
    [....]

</manifest>
```

In this way Google Play Store should not list your app for devices which doesn't have a SIM or radio communications.

More info [here in the *Telephony hardware features* section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features)